# Groups in linear regression with different intercepts. How do I find the differing variable?

Tags: regression, clustering, linear-model, intercept

This is more of a conceptual question.
I have a coefficient estimate of .80 in a linear regression model with one IV and one dependent variable. However, plotting the data I see distinct groups, differing by the intercept. 
I have about 300 additional variables in the data set that could have (or could not have; maybe it's something we didn't ask) an impact on the different intercept. 
I want to find the variables that explain the difference between these groups.

What I thought about so far:

- I won't find it with a moderation model because the difference is in the intercept, not the slope
- I already tried separating the groups and conducted `t.test()` on all of the 300 additional variables, but isn't there a more formal way to find the differing variable(s)?

I hope I could adequately describe the problem... I include a plot of the two variables. Can someone give me a hint?

> [image]

Comment: What do you mean by "regression weight" there?

Comment: The "estimate" output of the summary(lm()) function - is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by correct. Are you asking if it's okay call the estimate of the coefficient a regression weight? Some people call them that, but the phrase 'regression weight' has more than one possible interpretation, which is why I asked for clarification of what you intended.

Comment: What's the dependent variable?

Comment: I understand, thank you. Then: Yes, I mean the estimates of the coefficient. I will change that in the original question.

Comment: Both the dependent and the independent variable are chronological age measured in years